# Deleting File and Directory in JUnit

Tags: java, file, junit, delete-file

I'm writing a test for a method that creates a file in a directory. Here's what my JUnit test looks like:

```
  @Before
  public void setUp(){
      objectUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();
      //assign another directory path for testing using powermock
      WhiteBox.setInternalState(objectUnderTest, "dirPathField", mockDirPathObject);

      nameOfFile = "name.txt";
      textToWrite = "some text";
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldCreateAFile(){


      //create file and write test
      objectUnderTest.createFile(nameOfFile, textToWrite);
      /* this method creates the file in mockPathObject and performs
         FileWriter.write(text);
         FileWriter.close();
      */

      File expect = new File(mockPathObject + "\\" + nameOfFile);
      assertTrue(expect.exist());

      //assert if text is in the file -> it will not be called if first assert fails
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown(){
       File destroyFile = new File(mockPathObject + "\\" + nameOfFile);
       File destroyDir = new File(mockPathObject);

       //here's my problem
       destroyFile.delete(); //why is this returning false?
       destroyDir.delete(); //will also return false since file was not deleted above

  }
```

I was able to delete the File using deleteOnExit() but I will not be able to delete the directory using delete or deleteOnExit. I will also perform other test for other scenarios in this test script so I don't want to use deleteOnExit.

I don't know why I cannot delete it in JUnit test script while I can delete a file created and modified by FileWriter in runtime when the code is not a JUnit test. I also tried performing an infiniteLoop after the test method and delete the file manually but it tells me that other program is still using the file though I'm able to modify its content.

Hope somebody can suggest a way to delete the files and directories created during the tests. Thanks :D

For more clarity, the method I test looks like this [Unit testing method that invokes FileWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878716/unit-testing-method-that-invokes-filewriter)

Edit:Here is the method to test

```
    public void createFile(String fileName, String text){

           //SOME_PATH is a static string which is a field of the class
           File dir = new File(SOME_PATH); //I modified SOME_PATH using whitebox for testing

           if(!dir.exists()){
                booelan createDir = dir.mkdirs();
                if(!createDir){
                           sysout("cannot make dir");
                           return;
                }
           }


           try{
                 FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName, true);
                 fileWrite.write(text);
                 fileWrite.close();
           }
           catch(Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
           }

    }
```

I cannot modify this method as other developers created it. I was just instructed to create unit tests for test automation. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure `objectUnderTest.createFile(nameOfFile, textToWrite);
` release all resources i.e. closes any associated stream / writer ?

Comment: objectUnderTest.createFile(nameOfFile, textToWrite); performs a FileWriter.close() after creating and writing on file. I also tried doing objectUnderTest=null on tearDown but I still cannot delete the file

Comment: I would use a different file name for each test. You can generate the name with a counter.

Comment: I think I still cannot delete the directory even I delete those files using deleteOnExit() since I cannot do it with a single file

Comment: Let us see how objectUnderTest.createFile is handling/closing the FileWriter.

Comment: I also had the same problem and after reading advice by A4L I started checking every input AND output streams, associated with this file: as soon as I ensured that every stream is closed I could delete the file in tearDown method!

Answer (score 15):

Use the @Rule annotation and the `TemporaryFolder` classfor the folder that you need to delete.

*http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/Rule.html* (404 not found)

Update example of usage by http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html:

```
public static class HasTempFolder {

  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();

  @Test
  public void testUsingTempFolder() throws IOException {
    File createdFile= folder.newFile("myfile.txt");
    File createdFolder= folder.newFolder("subfolder");
    // ...
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't think I can use TemporaryFolder since the method I'm testing is the one creating the Folder and the file

Comment: Can you make the folder you want to create a folder inside of a TemporaryFolder? ie: mockDirPath is a subfolder of the TemporaryFolder.

Comment: Maybe.. as long as I will not modify the Class under test. I will try and hope the files under temporaryFolder will be gone after the test :D. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I usually clean up files:

```
@AfterClass
public static void clean() {
    File dir = new File(DIR_PATH);
    for (File file:dir.listFiles()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    dir.delete();
}
```

Your directory must be empty in order to delete it, make sure no other test methods are creating more files there.

**Ensure you are closing the FileWriter instance in a finally block**.

Comment: yes but the problem is I cannot delete the file even though I am sure that the FileWriter is closed in the method under test. I also cannot perform this if I delete the file using deleteOnExit

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that the method `objectUnderTest.createFile(nameOfFile, textToWrite)` actually closes any opened streams?

Comment: objectUnderTest.createFile(...) performs a FileWriter.close(); after creating and writing to file

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approche is te delete after JVM exit :

```
Path tmp = Files.createTempDirectory(null);
tmp.toFile().deleteOnExit();
```

Comment: Warning about deleteOnExit:  if you call deleteOnExit a lot say for temporary files, and your application runs for a long time, eg JBoss application server, then you may get OutOfMemory errors as VM is tracking a very long list of files to delete at System.exit which does not occur.