# Testing a function which checks for the existence of files with Junit4

Tags: java, gradle, junit4

Using Gradle with Junit4, how can I write tests for a function which checks if a set of files exist?
I want to test the case where the files do not exist, and the case where they do exist. It is my understanding that test cases in Junit4 shouldn't be order-dependent which is where I ran into a problem, my test for the case where they do exist runs first and copies the files to the directory, and they are there when the case where they do not exist runs.

I tried using the below code to delete the files before running the case where they do not exist, but using `Files.delete()` I found that they cannot be deleted because they are being used by a process, but the only process which would be using these files is the test suite itself so I am not sure how to get around this.

```java
public static void clean() {
    String buildDir = "build/classes/java/main/";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
        ClassLoader cl = SkippedReportTest.class.getClassLoader();
        InputStream in = cl.getResourceAsStream("input.properties");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(buffer);
        File propsFile = new File(buildDir + "input.properties");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(propsFile);
        out.write(buffer);
        InputStream propsIn = cl.getResourceAsStream("input.properties");
        props.load(propsIn);
        String directory = props.getProperty("directory");
        String prefix = props.getProperty("prefix");
        String[] names = props.getProperty("names").split(",");
        String extension = props.getProperty("extension");
        for (String name : names) {
            String report = directory + "/" + prefix + name + extension;
            File delete = new File(buildDir + report);
            Files.delete(delete.toPath());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the error that I am getting from the `Files.delete()` call:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: build\classes\java\main\MyFile.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Here is the test case that is failing because the files are copied to the folder before the test is run, and they cannot be deleted:

```java
@Test
public void testReportsExistFalse() {
    SkippedReportTest.clean();
    SkippedReport classUnderTest = new SkippedReport();
    assertFalse("Return false when reports aren't there",
                classUnderTest.reportsExist());
}
```

Comment: Instead of explicitly deleting, why not call `delete.deleteOnExit()` and let the JVM delete the file?

Comment: Hi Weston, have you looked at [Deleting File and Directory in JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884141/deleting-file-and-directory-in-junit)? It looks like there is a `TemporaryFolder` class for this use case.

Comment: @Brydenr Hi, thank you so much, this is definitely the right direction. The problem is that TemporaryFolder creates the folder at runtime (such as `junit10557557701318582316/`), so my function cannot check inside that folder for the existence of the file.